# Firefox can't access iframe print on the same domain

Tags: javascript, firefox, iframe, printing

I have an iframe on my page that displays a PDF that is located on the same domain. Because of how this system is built, I am required to use full paths in my src tags (e.g http://www.example.com/test.pdf). When I try to print i get the following error:

> Error: Permission denied to access property 'print'

If I remove "http://www.example.com/", Firefox is able to print, but that messes up other parts of the system.

So it seems that Firefox thinks that the iframe src is on a different domain just because i use full paths, but it isn't. Is there a workaround for this?

My print code:

```
$('#iframe')[0].focus();
$('#iframe')[0].contentWindow.print();
```

Answer (score 2):

A work around for this would be to use css @media. Refer an example below,

```
<BODY>
<STYLE type="text/css">
@media print 
{
  .dontprint{display:none} 
}
</STYLE>
<SCRIPT type="text/javascript">
function printPdf(){
        window.frames["printf"].focus();
        try {
            window.frames["printf"].print();
        }
        catch(e){
            window.print();
            console.log(e);
        }
    }
</SCRIPT>

<DIV class="dontprint" >
Some of your content here
<form><input type="button" onClick="printPdf()" value="Print"/></form>
...
...
</div>
<IFrame id="printf" src="whatever"></IFRAME>
<DIV class="dontprint" >
more content
...
...

</div>
</BODY>
```

[Refer this for discussion](http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?f=38&p=9646325)