# Firefox - iframe - 'Permission denied to access property "document" on cross-origin object' even on same origin

Tags: html, iframe, same-origin-policy

I have a test.pdf and a simple test.html file on my webserver (using the `https://` protocol):

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
    <iframe src="/test.pdf" onload="this.contentWindow.document;"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

I try to access the content of the iframe, which works fine in Chrome, however raises an error in Firefox:

```
Permission denied to access property "document" on cross-origin object
```

I've tried to use `this.contentDocument` (returns `null`), and use the full URI of the pdf (only differs in the last characters: `html` -> `pdf`, so should be same origin), but I get the same error. I'm using Firefox's native PDF viewer, if that matters.

Is it a bug in Firefox? Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error: Permission denied to access property "document"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36333978/error-permission-denied-to-access-property-document)

Comment: @koushikdeb If so, can you explain, how? Do you mean the accepted answer? To call a third party service to fetch the pdf from my own server then send it over to my client? Sounds super hacky to say the least. I don't want to rely on any third party, and my clients/server aren't even necessarily connected to the internet. Or the one with the most votes saying the same-origin policy is violated? I explicitly stated I believe this is not the case.

Comment: Extremely sorry for the mess up from my end. However, I searched for it and found this. Don't know if this can be helpful to you. Please check this one as well. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17989759/firefox-cant-access-iframe-print-on-the-same-domain

Thanks.

Comment: @koushikdeb Thanks, but I've seen it already. Here the op experiences a similar error only when using full paths. I get the error no matter if I use the full URI or not. The discussion linked in the answer is again about violating the same origin policy, and offers a workaround when you want to print the contents of the iframe. It's quite interesting, but doesn't help accessing the frame's contentDocument, and I don't want to print the iframe.

Comment: You mention that you see this "on (your) server", is this actually happening on a remote server or are you getting this when running locally? Relative paths on a server **should** be fine, the primary players in determining CORS issues are `protocol`, `host`, and `port`. The resource path (assuming all else is the same) should not trigger a cross-origin issues **unless** you are running this locally, in which case it would be accessing by `file://` instead of `http(s)://`.

Comment: @gmiley Thanks, the two files are on a webserver, I'm using the `https://` protocol.

Comment: I've got the same problem only on Firefox (works fine in Edge and Chrome). Additionally, I've discovered that it worked on Firefox if the src iframe was an image (even if it's better to have <img> tag but it was just as a test). Bug happens when loading pdf in the iframe (same for pdf, it's probably better to use <object> or <embed> tag)